# Is it possible to not use asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I don't want to use asset pipeline, can I just keep my css/js/images in the /public folder?

I'm migrating an old 2.x app and don't want to deal with the asset pipeline at this point.

Any gotchas if I do this?

Comment: Yep, keeping them in `/public` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just ad in `config/application.rb` following line:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```